# how to bind and show array of array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm trying to bind and show the value of array. When I'm assigning the value with the scope variable like this:

```
$scope.StockList = obj.data
```

It's working fine but when I'm pushing the value inside the array like this

```
$scope.StockList.push(obj.data);
```

It is not working as expected

Here I'm stuck with ng-repeat and scope variable. Can any one help me 
here is my effort.

```
$scope.StockList = [];
$scope.IsVisible = false;
var Stocks = [];

function GetStockEntries(loid, pid) {
  var data = { LocationId: loid, ProductId: pid }
  return $http.post(serviceURL + "/GetLocationStockEntries", data).then(
    function success(data, status, headers, config) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(data.data.d)

      //working fine in case single array
      //$scope.StockList = obj.data
      $scope.StockList.push(obj.data);    
    },
    function error(data, status, headers, config) {
      return data
    }
  )
}

$scope.StockListing = function (item) {
  debugger
  $scope.IsVisible = !$scope.IsVisible
  console.log($scope.StockList)
}
```

ng repeat code

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="stocktransferdiv">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" data-ng-repeat="stockItem in StockList" data-ng-show = "IsVisible" data-ng-cloak width="100%">                                            
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; float: left;">
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="groupName" data-ng-value="true" data-ng-model="stockItem.selected" data-ng-change="onTaskSelect(stockItem)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.UserInventoryItemID"disabled="" readonly="" style="border: none; background-color: white;">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.LotNumber" disabled="" readonly="">
          </td>
          <td>
            <!--<input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.QuantityOnHand" disabled="" readonly="">-->
            <span>{{stockItem.QuantityOnHand}}</span>
            <span>{{stockItem.UnitName}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.EnteredQuantity" >
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.Description" disabled="" readonly="">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the result of that json

[image]

Comment: Show us the structure of obj.data

Comment: @Sajeetharan : Updated with the obj.data result

Comment: You need to push the object not the property, try something like this, $scope.StockList.push(obj);

Comment: @Sajeetharan : i also tried that.

Comment: working on official computer, i dont have the rights sir!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125773/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-miranda).

Comment: why you removed answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service returns an array of objects, you need to loop over them and add it to the array,

```
var obj = data.data.d; 
$scope.result = obj ;
$scope.result.forEach(function(key) { 
$scope.StockList.push(key); 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

just a little bit modification of accepted answer. it will work .try this one.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data.data.d);
        $scope.result = obj.data;
        angular.forEach($scope.result, function (key) {
            $scope.StockList.push(key);
        })
```